# multi_match query returning no results elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying a multi_match query in ElasticSearch but the query is returning no results. The query is:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/smartjn/feed_details/_search" -d'
{
    "query" : {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query" : "Dho*",
            "fields" : [ "title", "wardname" ]
        }
    }
}'
{"took":11,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

I have value in wardname field starting with Dho,

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("56f43c0344fc86e73b1170b0"),
     title: "Constant road work",
     approvalStatus: "approved",
     subward: "56a6124244fc868a255fe3fe",
     wardname: "Dhokali"
    }
```

not sure why is it not returning anything. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Phrase Prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix) query if you want to search something that **starts with** some string. Try following query.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/smartjn/feed_details/_search" -d'
{
    "query" : {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query" : "Dho*",
            "fields" : [ "title", "wardname" ],
            "type': 'phrase_prefix"
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: You just saved my life sir. Hats off!

Comment: glad I could help!